# UIView different values for width with a portrait mode

Tags: ipad, uiview

The Auto Resizing for the UIView's. in Xcode shows the value (0,20,768,1024)however user can't change it in Xcode but if try to repint out the width of the view in your code :

```
    NSLog(@"Board view w %f", self.view.size.width);
NSLog(@"Board view h %f", self.view .size.height);
```

the values that you get for the width  with a portrait  are 1024  or 1004

I would like to know in the case of 1004 as width what will happen for the remaining  20 pixels ?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You probably are not counting the 20px of the top `UIStatusBar`.

You can also set the `frame` manually.

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    NSLog(@"didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation");
    if( orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024)];
    } else {
        [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768)];
    }
}
```

Comment: I ‘m developing a  small iPad application  , UIView  (title image  as UIImage 200 px height  , background as UIImage 700 px height  and bar as UImage  124 px height)
But I have added a button to play a video and I have set my movie player frame to my view bounds  code is below :

[moviePlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
after the movie finished playing  ,my view display was wrong  due to a shift 20 px 
My question how I can set my moviePlayer.view to (0,0, 768.1024) for portrait mode  and (0.0,1024,768)for landscape mode 
many thanks in advance

Comment: I've edited the answer with suggestion to change the frame manually.